# Fix div height in right of div

Tags: css, html, css-float

i have any div for show details of project ( class main ). now i need to 2 columns. right / left . i need to fix right div with `30px width` and `height 100%` & 'auto' and `fix in right`. left columns `height:auto` and `overflow:hidden`.

Html :

```
<div class="main">
<div class="right">
</div>
<div class="left">
.... Descripton .....
</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {width:300px; height:auto; overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;}
.right{width:30px; float:right; height:auto; background-color:#e1e1e1; }
.left{width:270px; float:right; height:auto;}
```

Online demo my problem : [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VbMey/1/) in this i didint see right div with backgroud-color:#e1e1e1;

i need to this : [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unhic.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fbUQB/. That is what you are asking for, isn't it?

Comment: If one of these days you want to figure out what's going on under there: http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight

Comment: -1.  This answer is lacking any description of how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with absolute positions (position:absolute).

float:right/left is rather an abuse

```
<div style="position:relative;width:300px; height:200px;margin:0 auto; background-color:#00ff00;">
 <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0;background-color:#ff0000;color:#000;">  Your right content
  </div>
  &nbsp;
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0;background-color:#0000ff;color:#000;">
    Left content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You do not answer my question. my mean if left div height chenged to down/ right div so changed and to down

Answer (score 0):

So I believe you want to make 2 columns besides each other with the right column having a lightgrey background.

They should both be 100% in height. To make stuff 100% high we need to set the `html` and `body` tags to 100% as well.

I believe [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/VbMey/30/) does what you want. Excuse me for changing the background color a bit, and I set the left column to `overflow: auto` to test.